# How to prevent IE10 auto scroll to the textarea on focus, when the textarea is actually in sight

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

I just found that IE10 ( maybe also IE9 and IE8 ) will eagerly scroll to the cursor place in textarea when I `focus` a textarea in jQuery, even if the textarea and the cursor is in sight. It will scroll to the textarea so closely, which is really disturbing.

I made an online example: http://larryzhao.com/test.html.

I put a large `div` on page to push the textarea a little bit bottom of the page and call `focus` on textarea on page load.

Then you could see that on opening the page with IE10, it will automatically scroll to the textarea even it is already insight, on the contrary, Chrome will not.

And I placed a fixed `<a>` on top, it will also call `focus` on the textarea when clicked. So if you scroll to top and click the link with the textarea in sight, IE10 will still perform the scroll.

And I have two questions:

1. Is there an easy way to prevent IE10 ( or IE9/8 ) from doing this? In order to achieve the same behaviour as in Chrome.
2. Is there any other action which would trigger this odd behaviour in IE10?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Off topic, try [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for your future references.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var top = $('textarea').offset().top;
    function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
        var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

        var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
        return (docViewBottom > elemTop);
    }
    if (!isScrolledIntoView($('textarea')[0])) {
        $('textarea').focus(function () {
            $(window).scrollTop(top-120);
        });
    } else {
        $('textarea').focus(function () {
            $(window).scrollTop(0);
        });
    }

    $('textarea').focus();
    $('a').click(function () {
        $('textarea').focus();
    });
});
```